# JAI installation/use

Tags: java, jai

I made a Java class using JAI. The class was working fine in Netbeans. Now I have to add *cmd.exe* and *javac*.

However, now the class is not working, whatever I've tried from the JAI library.
Here is where I use JAI on my class.

```
import javax.media.jai.JAI;
import javax.media.jai.RenderedImageAdapter;
...
RenderedImage rendimg=JAI.create("fileload","/Users/Blob/Desktop/projet_jni/ressources/init.pgm");
BufferedImage init = new RenderedImageAdapter(rendimg).getAsBufferedImage();
```

I tried to install JAI with the   jai-1_1_3-lib-windows-i586-jdk.exe.
I tried to use jai-1_1_3-lib-windows-i586.jar like that (in the cmd) :

```
javac -cp ../ressources/ressources.jar;../ressources/jai_windows-i586.jar *.java
```

It compiles normally, but I always get the error :

```
C:\Users\USER\Desktop\projet_jni\part_java>java Main
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/jai/JAI
    at ImgProcessing.<init>(ImgProcessing.java:46)
    at Fenetre.<init>(Fenetre.java:23)
    at Main.main(Main.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.media.jai.JAI
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

How can I repair this issue?

EDIT :

tried for the same error :

```
java -classpath "../ressources/ressources.jar;../ressources/jai_windows-i586.jar;." Main
```

tried :

```
java -cp ../ressources/ressources.jar;../ressources/jai_windows-i586.jar Main
```

"Main" can't be found or loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the same class path when running your application, as when you compiled it.

I.e.:

```
java -cp .;../ressources/ressources.jar;../ressources/jai_windows-i586.jar Main
```

Comment: Thank you!
I tried that but it says me that the Main class can not be found or loaded. tried to do the other way (see edit) but it don't change anything.

Comment: @user3178283: I updated the answer, now including current directory in classpath. Without quotes.

Comment: There is now the first error again : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/jai/JAI

Comment: If on OS X or Linux/Unix, try replacing all ; with : on the command line. I assumed Windows. Different platforms has different separators, has nothing to do with Java.

Comment: Hi sorry for the delay, but i'm working with windows. I think maybe I'll try to setup the "Java Advanced Imaging-Image I/O" just in case but I don't think it's from that.